# Updating records in a table using GetCount and an Update Cursor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

What I have is a buffer which is then used to select a number of point features which intersect the polygon. I would like to take that number and add the value to a table. The row where the value will need to be located corresponds with the name of the original feature class the buffer was created from.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
from os.path import join



arcpy.env.workspace = r'MyWorkspace'
updateTable = r'table'
shortField = "FieldName"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("FieldName", "fieldname_layer")
fcs = arcpy.arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*_Value", "POLYGON")
for fc in fcs:
    select = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("fieldname_layer", "INTERSECT", short)
    result = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(select).getOutput(0))
    print short.replace('Buffer_','') + " " + str(result)
```

So far the best I can come up with is printing the file name less the Buffer_ portion which precedes the name I need. I cannot wrap my head around how to go from there to updating only relevant records using the update cursor.

Comment: What version of arcmap are you using? At 10.1+, you have access to the data access module cursors.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention 10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment your code looks like it would produce errors.

I think you should change it from:

```
fcs = arcpy.arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*_Value", "POLYGON")
for fc in fcs:
    select = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("fieldname_layer", "INTERSECT", short)
    result = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(select).getOutput(0))
    print short.replace('Buffer_','') + " " + str(result)
```

to:

```
print short  # we cannot see what it is set to but it seems to be a layer or geometry object
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*_Value", "POLYGON")
for fc in fcs:
    select = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("fieldname_layer", "INTERSECT", short)
    result = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(select).getOutput(0))
    print result
    print short.replace('Buffer_','') + " " + str(result)
```

However, mainly I think you should look at [Does ArcPy have a spatial search function for geometry?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/does-arcpy-have-a-spatial-search-function-for-geometry/27352#27352) because I think it may provide you with a better starting point for your code.