# Create Separate Layers by Category

Tags: arcpy, cursor, loop

I'm trying to create a layer for each county (based on a layer of all counties) and join only those census tracts located in that county. However, the result I'm getting is a layer named for each county but has all counties and census tracks.

```
coFC = r"C:\TenCounties" 
coField = "County_Name" 
censusFC = r"C:CT.shp"

# Get a unique list of the counties
values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(coFC, (coField))]
list_of_counties = set(values)

# Create a feature layer for the Census Tracts
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(censusFC, "lyr_Census")

for county in list_of_counties:
    print county
    # Create a feature layer that contains just the current county
    newout_name = arcpy.ValidateTableName(county)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(coFC, newout_name, "\"County_Name\" = '{0}'".format(county))
    # Select the census tracts that are located in the current county
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lyr_Census", "INTERSECT",    newout_name)
    #Create a layer for each County
    rcpy.CopyFeatures_management(coFC, "lyr_" + newout_name)
```

Comment: Perhaps look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27352/115 and adapt for arcpy.da rather than arcpy cursors for another approach, but I think your problem is that you are using CopyFeatures on `coFC` when it should be `"lyr_Census"`.

Comment: In `CopyFeatures`, you are passing the original shapefile, `coFC`. You probably intend to be using the result from select. Edit: argh! beaten by two seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned twice in comments, you're using your input feature class as your export. You want to use your selected features instead I'm assuming.

Change:

`rcpy.CopyFeatures_management(coFC, "lyr_" + newout_name)`

to:

`arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("lyr_Census", "lyr_" + newout_name)`

You're not actually creating a layer here though. You're creating a feature class. If you instead want a `.lyr` file, use:

`arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management ("lyr_Census", "lyr_" + newout_name + ".lyr")`

You'll probably want to set the workspace (`arcpy.env.workspace`) to the folder or geodatabase you wish your layers or feature classes to be exported to as well.

Comment: Yea, that's all it was. Thanks PolyGeo, Paul and Emil!