# Is there a Select Feature by Attribute tool for Feature Classes when performing selection ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-9.3, modelbuilder, select

I want to perform a Select by Attribute selection on a Feature Class in ModelBuilder, but I know the Select by Attribute tool does not work in this situation.  I need to perform this function as I want to avoid creating an additional dataset.  This task is the second to last one, the last one being a Delete Rows.

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between feature class and feature layer?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/whats-the-difference-between-feature-class-and-feature-layer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the Make Feature Layer tool on your feature class first, then you will be able to use Select Layer By Attribute on that.

Comment: See also the help topic on [Using layers and table views](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00210000000m000000), I think this provides a pretty good overview.