# Can QGIS or GRASS convert layer files to shapefiles?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, layer-file

Should I be downloading QGIS or GRASS?

I want the program with the most features. Most importantly, I have a lot of .lyr files. Can either of these softwares convert to shp and if so, how can I do it?

I've tried exporting through grass, it runs but no image appears. It says something about "try setting parameters".

Comment: Aren't `.lyr` files [just symbology](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54111/how-to-explain-what-layer-file-lyr-in-arcgis-desktop-is)? AFAIK, they can't be converted to `.shp` by any piece of software because a `.shp` represents underlying data that a `.lyr` only knows the location of (on disk).

Comment: If you give us more details we can help you...

With this info I can tell that QGIS probably works, if you need there is also Grass plugin available

Answer (score 1):

you should downloading QGIS,  as it is nowadays coming with GRASS inbuilt in it as a pugin.
QGIS is capable of handling all layer vector layers with shapefiles.