# Changing default point symbol?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, point

I am trying to change the default point layer symbol to a set one.  For example I have a fire hydrant point layer that is represented by a default point symbol when I import it into my map.  Is there a way I can change the default symbol to one I select and it will continue to be the default point symbol?

Comment: Have you tried working with layer files? See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54111/how-to-explain-what-layer-file-lyr-in-arcgis-desktop-is

Comment: If your chosen symbol name matches values in your feature it might be applied by "default".  See http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/tutorials/3d_analyst/3D_9_7.htm

Answer (score 1):

From [ESRI Mapping Center](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=1234):

> The default symbology can be changed using the Advanced ArcMap Settings Utility.  This executable file is usually found in your C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Utilities directory.  Just navigate to that directory, double click the AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe file and the ArcMap Advanced Settings dialog will open.  Click the Symbols/Graphics tab and you can set the color ramp and the color scheme (Pastels by default), as well as the background color (white by default), the marker size (4 pts by default), the line width (1 pt by default), the rectangle style (solid by default), and the rectangle outline width (1 pt by default) as well as many other settings that relate to your experience in ArcMap.

Comment: Thank you!  With this method can I change the default on just a single layer?  Example if I want fire hydrants to have their own default point layer?

Comment: The default. I don't think you can for a single layer. Maybe someone else can help; more answers should be posted soon. I'll do my research and edit my answer if I find anything.

Comment: There's some other location for the drawing toolbar default for purely graphic point is controlled.  Currently I have a default point graphic that is stuck on no color, driving me insane.