# ArcGIS Feature Class verse Feature Layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers

In general is it better (more efficient) to work with Feature Classes (FC) or Feature Layers (a feature layer of a FC). I know when I construct model I always (or generally) work with feature layers which got me to think that maybe layers were more efficient (especially with very very large feature classes.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59837/why-is-it-important-to-use-feature-layers-in-modelbuilder

Comment: Feature layers have more options, like Select Layer by Attribute etc.. and may not represent all the features in a feature class. Some tools (like Add Join) require a feature layer and not a feature class. Feature Layers need to be made in ArcCatalog and command but can be referenced directly from ArcMap. I would use a feature class over a feature layer unless I want to use a subset or other property of a layer, but that's just me. I don't think either one is any faster.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I don't follow 'need to be made in ArcCatalog and command'. There is, after all, the Make Feature Layer GP tool, and the ability to right-click a layer in the ToC and create a new feature layer from selected. In fact, I thought (perhaps incorrectly) that the layers in an ArcMap ToC *were* feature layers (which is why some model tools can use ToC layers as inputs successfully but will fail if referencing the feature class directly). I don't know enough about programming/processing to address efficiency, but the question I linked to discusses in-memory vs disk access.

Comment: @ChrisW, when executing a python tool in ArcMap the layers can be taken from the map *by name* because they already exist. If you execute a python tool from ArcCatalog or on the command line you must create a layer with MakeFeatureLayer or use a layer file (already saved) in order to use a layer. There is no mention in the question about "in_memory" although that would be one way to speed things up, especially with outputs from each step in a process, the question is about Feature Class (full path) vs Feature Layer.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Ah, that makes more sense. The question is actually a bit broad and open to interpretation, because it's asking which is 'better or more efficient to work with' - and my first thought was work with *how*? I was thinking a layer was an in-memory kind of thing by default, whereas a feature class was on disk and I guess could be entirely loaded into memory. But I'm at like level 0 on programming, so how things are loaded when and where they persist vs having to be loaded again is not something I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

As somebody told in an ESRI forum in 2003 *"Feature Layer is a layer in your map"* so it means that a Feature Layer is a single entity (polilyne, point or polygon) wich can be put as a simple object in your map or consider as a "mask" of a "Feature Class". But *"Feature Class is a dataset that resides on disk"*.

Comment: Yes Chris you are absolutely right, I have committed a HUGE mistake, my apologies.........