# Why does ArcMap drag and drop report "one or more dropped items invalid"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, tools, arccatalog

I've noticed that I can drag and drop data sets into a custom tool within ArcCatalog 10.1, but if I launch the tool in ArcMap and try to drag and drop layers already in my TOC, I get an error

> one or more dropped items invalid

but I can browse to it and load that way.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your custom tool is expecting a **dataset** rather than a **layer**.

Consequently, when you drag and drop a dataset in ArcCatalog all is fine.

However, when you try to drag and drop a layer from the Table of Contents it rightly complains that it is not a dataset.

Try drag and drop of the dataset, which is the source of the same layer, from the Catalog window of ArcMap and I expect that will work.

To make your tool accept either a dataset or a layer take a look at the type of data element that parameter is based on in your model.

To more clearly appreciate the difference between a layer (listed in the Table of Contents of ArcMap) and a spatial dataset (listed in the Catalog window of ArcMap and in ArcCatalog) I recommend reviewing [Difference between map layer and spatial dataset (e.g. feature class, shapefile)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/whats-the-difference-between-feature-class-and-feature-layer)

Answer (score 0):

Also, this error can occur because of fact that your raster values are not interger data type.
Convert it (ArcToolbox / Spatial Analyst Tools / Math / Int) and try again using this output. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Adrian's answer worked for me.

Also, this error can occur because if your raster values are not integer data type. Convert it (ArcToolbox / Spatial Analyst Tools / Math / Int) and try again using this output.