# Line density to polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster

I have performed Line Density and the results is a Raster...I want to make polygons from this Raster, but I cannot do it...

It shows me when I put this raster as Input raster:

"One or more Dropped items were invalid and will not be added to the control."

Does someone know how to do this job in ArcGIS 10.1?

[image: Raster to Polygon failure]

Comment: Did you make sure your road layer is free from any missing values, dangles, and other minor errors? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01020000005m000000

Comment: My road network is all okay..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the objection that the "Raster to Polygon" tool is making is simply that there are too many floating point values to make polygons out of. I doubt that you actually want a separate polygon for each cell.

What I would do would be to generalize the raster into categories that make sense (you could use the cutoff values from the classification). I'd make these into integer values and then run the raster to polygon tool.

If you have Spatial Analyst, you should be able to generalize the raster using Reclassify or Con (though I think it would be easiest with Reclassify).

**EDIT:** To further assert that this is the problem, see the Help documentation for the [Raster to Polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000008000000) tool which states (referring to the in_raster): "The raster must be integer type."

Comment: that may be a right and smart observation, yet it should not cause such an error. If that was the case, it was either taking forever to process, or crashing the software

Comment: However it does cause that error and this can be duplicated.

Comment: not sure. since if your solution will work it might be better to edit the question and title.

Comment: You might want to edit your original answer since the problem is not "too many floating point values", but it is that the values are in float, rather than in integer.

Comment: You were right...there are too many floating point values to make a polygon. I used Reclassify and it works fine now. Thanks for your answer..

Answer (score 0):

this was already asked in this forum - [see attached](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83289/why-does-arcmap-drag-and-drop-report-one-or-more-dropped-items-invalid)

You should choose, or drag and drop, your raster to the tool's input field from the Catalog, rather than from the table of contents.

Hope this solce your probelm

Comment: That post refers to custom tools. The built-in ESRI tools are usually robust enough to take a dataset or a layer as input.

Comment: @jbchurchill I dissagree with you. From my experience with Arcmap 9.x - 10.2 the Built-In ESRI tools do not always function as expected while dragging from the table of contents. Anyway Ycavazin should give some more deatils about what were his/hers exact actions...

Comment: Thanks @dof1985 for the information, but unfortunatelly this is not the case...