# Why are representations functions accessible in Table of Contents not in Catalog window of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, representation, catalog-window

It's really frustrating that adding a new representation form the Catalog window of ArcMap  does not work while it works for TOC when adding the required lyr file as a symbology then right click and "convert symbology to representation", why it's not working from the Catalog window?

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, from the Catalog window:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the software behaviour you are observing is by design.

I recommend reviewing [Difference between map layer and spatial dataset (e.g. feature class, shapefile)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/what-is-difference-between-map-layer-and-spatial-dataset-e-g-feature-class-sh) and then think of the:

- **Table of Contents** window as being the place where you do things with **symbology**
- **Catalog** window as being the place where you do things with **data**

Cartographic representations are about symbolizing and so you would expect to see more access to the functionality that involves them in the Table of Contents than in the Catalog window.

I suspect that the reason Representations can appear in the Properties of a feature class in the Catalog window is that they are stored as columns in a geodatabase.

The design appears to be a sensible compromise between having the data properties of representations accessible in the Catalog window without having all functions from the Table of Contents related to creating representations duplicated there.

Comment: Many Thanks PolyGeo,form your answer I guess that I cant do it from the catalog window, but the question is why ? why ESRI included it in the proprieties  of the feature class?