# make feature layer of shapefile

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, feature-layer

I'm trying to use polygons in arcpy. The polygons are stored in a [shapefile](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/78l1aptn6le2q3l/AACYAenYjdvHxcbGyvJhcWzUa?dl=0). When running the following:

```
import arcpy 
gdb = 'path//to//gbd' 
inshape = os.path.join(folder,'Ameland_1968.shp') 
poly = os.path.join(gdb,'test')

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (inshape, poly)
```

I get this error:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000229: Cannot open inshape **(red: this path is typed out)
Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).
```

What is the problem? Arcpy should be able to run this line with shapefiles right? I'm actually trying to run a part of a script that's using arcpy but the data is in shapefiles. How to convert these?

edit: this is my original code

```
poly_shape = 'D:\\ARNO\\Analysis\\ArcGIS\\ArcPyScripts\\Data\\straight_bars_2\\Ameland\\Ameland_1965.shp'
poly = 'D:\\ARNO\\Analysis\\ArcGIS\\ArcPyScripts\\Data\\test.gdb\\Ameland65'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (poly_shape, poly)
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `MakeFeatureLayer` with `if arcpy.Exists(inshape): print("OK")` (with line break before `print`)? You haven't defined `folder` in your snippet above, which may or may not be the problem... a complete example is going to be important to help with debugging.

Comment: Show how you declare 'folder'. Also you cant place a feature layer in a geodatabase, it is created in memory. If you want to make it permanent use Copy Features afterwards. Syntax for Make Feature Layer: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm

Comment: It prints 'OK', the file exists. I thought I'd make it easier for the ones trying to replicate it. I'll paste exactly what I have.

Comment: You are confusing feature classes with feature layers. What is your next step after you have created a feature layer?

Comment: I'm putting it into the simplify function. But it makes sense that I mix up those. I'll look into this! Is there a one sentence difference or is this off topic?

Comment: Some geoprocessing tool want feature layer as inputs (like Select By Location) and some want feature classes (like a shapefile, or a feature class in a file geodatabase). So it depends on what you are going to do next in your code. See: http://support.esri.com/en/other-resources/gis-dictionary/browse

Comment: perfect, thank you very much! If you post the answer I will mark it as correct

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/difference-between-map-layer-and-spatial-dataset-e-g-feature-class-shapefile

Answer (score 4):

With `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management()` you just need to specify a *name* for your feature layer, not a path.  The feature layer still points back to your original shapefile as the source, it does not copy it to a new geodatabase feature class.

So instead of giving a path in the second parameter, just give it a string value like `"mypoly"`

```
poly_shape = 'D:\\ARNO\\Analysis\\ArcGIS\\ArcPyScripts\\Data\\straight_bars_2\\Ameland\\Ameland_1965.shp'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (poly_shape, "mypoly")
```

You can then reference `"mypoly"` elsewhere as an input for other tools such as the Simplify you mention above.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to make a feature layer from a gdb feature class.  You may point the Make Feature Layer method directly to the shapefile:

```
inshape = os.path.join('C:/myFolder/','Ameland_1968.shp') 
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inshape, 'myFeatureLayerName')
```